# What's the difference between /mtd and /mdd (in code generation property section) in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

What's the difference between specifying `/mdd` (multi-threaded debug dll) and `/mtd` (multi-threaded debug) in Visual Studio??

Answer (score 10):

`/mtd` requires a static link, to produce a `.exe` that's larger but **not** dependent on the DLL (that comes with VS2005) containing the runtime library.

Answer (score 3):

In general if your application is small and does not contain multiple DLLs or EXEs you may prefer to statically link to the runtime libraries.  This will simplify the distribution process since you will not need to install the runtime libraries.

If you have multiple DLLs or EXEs, since each EXE and DLL will be larger when statically linked as Alex stated, you may prefer to use dynamic linking to the runtime libraries making your application smaller.