# Debug Assertion Error in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I was doing line detection in OpenCV. Everything was going fine until i get this Debug assertion error:

> Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: _pFirstBlock == pHead

[image: Screenshot of the assertion]

I spent days working on it but cannot debug it. This is my code.

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main() {
VideoCapture stream1(0);  
while (true) {
    Mat cameraFrame;
    stream1.read(cameraFrame);
    imshow("cam", cameraFrame);

    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
        break;

    Mat src = cameraFrame;


    Mat dst, cdst;
    Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3);
    cvtColor(dst, cdst, CV_GRAY2BGR);

   vector<Vec4i> lines;

    HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI / 180, 50, 50, 10);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
    {
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    line(cdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3, CV_AA);
    }

    imshow("processed", cdst);


}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: please paste the *text* of the exception, not a screenshot..

Comment: also make sure, you don't mix debug/release libs

Comment: ERROR IS 
Debug assertion failed
Program:...al studio
2013\Projects\Opencv2.4.9\x64\Debug\OpenCV2.4.9.exe
File:f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\misc\dbgheap.c
Line:1424

Expression:_pFirstBlock==pHead

For more onformation on how your program can cause assertion
failure,see the visual C++ documentation on aserts.

Comment: nope i didnt mix the libraries code is working fine in release mode...but not in debug mode!!

Comment: If you click "Retry" to break at that assertion, you'll see it's trying to free some heap memory. Look at the call stack in the debugger and let us know which line in your source code is running.

Comment: In my code it is showing error on line 36 which is the closing parenthesis of while(true) statement..  

CallStack: OpenCV2.4.9.exe!main() Line 36 C++


Callstack is also showing one more file:xmemory0

Comment: @Siddhant The question is old but the problem continues to occur. I shared an answer that shows how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because OpenCV libraries are traditionally compiled with the following [runtime library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/919267/176769):

- **MD** (Release)
- **MDd** (Debug)

while my IDE **Qt Creator**, which uses **MSVC 2013** with it's default configuration, builds stuff with:

- **MT** (Release)
- **MTd** (Debug)

Surprisingly, the error only manifested when HOG's `compute()` was invoked.

*To fully understand the MT vs MD (runtime library) dilemma, [read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx).*

There are 2 different ways to handle this issue. The easy way out is to adjust your projects setting to also use MD/MDd as runtime library and match OpenCV's!

On Qt Creator, this can be done in the .pro file by adding:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG += /MDd
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += /MD
```

On the other hand, on some versions of Visual Studio this can be done through your `Project Properties >> Configuration Properties >> C/C++ >> Code Generation` and changing the `Runtime Library` to:

- **Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)**, if you are building the *Debug* version of your code.
- **Multi-threaded DLL(/MD)**, if you are building the *Release* version of your code.

The other way to handle this issue is to rebuild/recompile OpenCV with `BUILD_WITH_STATIC_CRT` **enabled**. This will compile OpenCV libraries with **MT/MTd** support.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe its the solution like the one, which helped for me.

You try using a Winforms with /clr specified for the GUI side calling into unmanaged code that at some point referenced a ATL header.

You need to bind the opencv Libarys in the linker dependencies ( opencv_calib2411d, ... care for Debug/Release and the opencv version you use)

additional:

add  __DllMainCRTStartup@12 in Force Symbols Reference section in the Linker section of the project settings.

source
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62db4002-4ebc-4a3a-91ec-9fc702db821e/crtisvalidheappointerpuserdata-why-is-this-code-broken-vs2008?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: It's a totally different problem.